# Failed to compile, Unexpected token if in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I cant seem to get this simple function to work basically my markup is like so(simplified)

```
{ loading || Object.keys(product).length <= 0 ? 'loading' :
  <div>
    {if(){

    }}
    <ProductPictureWidget mainPic={product.pic_url} />
    <ProductOptionsWidget product={product} activeProps={activeProps} selectProductOption={this.selectProductOption}/>
  </div>
}
```

But this leaves me with `SyntaxError: Unexpected token` on my `if` statement

What exactly am I doing wrong here am I not allowed to do `if` statements within my shorthand `if` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSX doesn't allow `if statement` within the return function. But you are allowed to use ternary expressions

```
{ loading || Object.keys(product).length <= 0 ? 'loading' :
  <div>
    {(condition here)? <div>Hello World</div>: null}
    <ProductPictureWidget mainPic={product.pic_url} />
    <ProductOptionsWidget product={product} activeProps={activeProps} selectProductOption={this.selectProductOption}/>
  </div>
}
```

However if you want to make use of `if statement` there is an alternative way to do it, i.e to call a function within which you use the `if-else statements`

```
conditionalRender() {
   if(condition) {
      return <div>Hello</div>
   } else {
      return null
  }
}

{ loading || Object.keys(product).length <= 0 ? 'loading' :
  <div>
    {this.conditionalRender()}
    <ProductPictureWidget mainPic={product.pic_url} />
    <ProductOptionsWidget product={product} activeProps={activeProps} selectProductOption={this.selectProductOption}/>
  </div>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

JSX only allows *expressions*, not statements. The [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) is an expression. `if` starts an [if *statement*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else). You can see why an if statement wouldn't work by looking at the compiled JavaScript (with the if statement removed):

```
{
  loading || Object.keys(product).length <= 0 ? 'loading' : React.createElement(
    'div',
    null,
    React.createElement(ProductPictureWidget, { mainPic: product.pic_url }),
    React.createElement(ProductOptionsWidget, { product: product, activeProps: activeProps, selectProductOption: undefined.selectProductOption })
  );
}
```

JSX amounts to function calls and object declarations. If the `if` statement were compiled, it would yield invalid JavaScript:

```
{
  loading || Object.keys(product).length <= 0 ? 'loading' : React.createElement(
    'div',
    null,
    if(){ }, // This is **invalid** JavaScript!!
    React.createElement(ProductPictureWidget, { mainPic: product.pic_url }),
    React.createElement(ProductOptionsWidget, { product: product, activeProps: activeProps, selectProductOption: undefined.selectProductOption })
  );
}
```

Comment: So to accomplish this I would have to remove the ternary operator completely and just write it as a if else statement right?

Comment: You can assign the conditionally-rendered component to a variable and reference the variable in the JSX or follow a pattern like in Shubham Khatri's answer.