# Return nothing using React render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have render in React component. If a condition is fulfilled I want to do something, in this case to show a message when hover over an icon but otherwise I don't want it to do anything.

I tried with an if condition but it doesn't work. This is my code:

```
render() {
    const text= this.checkSomething();

    return (
    {
       if (text.length > 0) {
            <ActionBar>
                <div>
                    <Icon type="..."/>
                     //do something here
                </div>
        </ActionBar>
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

> A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have
>   returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

I know that I return something that doesn' exist if `text.length == 0`, but is there any way to make it work, like don't return anything if the condition is not met?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If statement within shorthand if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42686424/if-statement-within-shorthand-if-statement)

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Very nice answer. You have typo: if statments :)

Comment: @VedranMaricevic, Thanks, fixed the typo :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have an `if` within the `return` of the `render()` function. Only ternary and short-circuit operations will work inside the `return`.

It's best to perform as much logic before your return.

Try this instead:

```
render() {
    const text= this.checkSomething();

    if(!text.length) return null;
    return (
      <ActionBar>
        <div>
          <Icon type="..."/>
          //do something here
        </div>
      </ActionBar>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you can have if as well inside return.

Comment: @VedranMaricevic, no it's not possible.

Comment: Sorry, but it is :)

Comment: @VedranMaricevic, can you show a fiddle or some kind of working demo of that?

Comment: Please check the link in the first OP comment.

Comment: @VedranMaricevic, yeah. The accepted answer even says *"JSX **doesn't allow** `if` statement within the return function."* :)

Comment: @Chris It kinda does though. But only if you wrap it in a function first. Like so: `return (<div>{ ( () => { if (catSay == 'maow') return: <p>meow</p> } )() }</div>);`.

Comment: @KevinFrostad, yeah true, but that is the same as invoking a method rather than creating a function inside the return. I've never seen such implementation and it's kinda weird, but you're right... I guess *you could*...

Comment: @Chris Yup, it's weird. But you never know, there might be a use case for it :D

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning the Component. Try this code:

```
render()
{
    const text = this.checkSomething();

    if (text.length > 0) {
        return ( <ActionBar>
            <div>
                <Icon type="..."/>
                //do something here
            </div>
        </ActionBar> )
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Will not work completely still, if the condition doesn't match, you will get  an error since nothing will be returned, `return null` is condition doesn't match. However its a duplicate question

Comment: Null should be returned, of course. But this answer is based on OP question.

Comment: Correct, but if you are posting an answer, make sure that it will work completely. You can just edit your answer. Also check the duplicate question

Comment: Edited. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In render, you need to return either a `React.Element` or `null`, so the shortest way could be like:

```
  render() {
    const text = this.checkSomething();

    return (
      text.length > 0 ? (
        <ActionBar>
          <div>
            <Icon type="..."/>
            //do something here
          </div>
        </ActionBar>
      ) : null
    ); 
  }
```

Read more about this here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html#render

Answer (score 0):

Its simple check for condition and return component or just null

```
render() {
const text= this.checkSomething();


   if (text.length > 0) {
       return <ActionBar>
            <div>
                <Icon type="..."/>
            </div>
    </ActionBar>
   }else{
      return null
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path. Just a little mistake. You should condition it like so:

```
render() {

  const text= this.checkSomething();

  if (text.length > 0) {
    return (
      <div>
        // do something
      </div>
    );
  }
  // if condition is not met
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>please wait while data is loading..</h1>
    </div>
  );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  construct() {
    //...
  }
  
  sometext() {
   return '123213';
  }
  
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
     {(this.sometext().length > 0) ? <ActionBar /> : null}
     </div>
    );
  }
  
}

const ActionBar = () => (
  <div>Super</div>
)

  ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in a function and then call itself, all within the `return`.

```
return (
    <div>
      {(() => {
        if (catSay == "maow") return <p>meow</p>;
      })()}
    </div>
  );
```