# GatsbyJs returns unexpected token "if" when compiling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have a simple code in gatsbyJs that gets data from  a Staticquery ingraphql and renders a component. I need to check in render function whether a sub-object within the data object exists and add a

html block with the data if the sub object exists.

Here the code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link, StaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'

export default () =>(
   <StaticQuery
   query={graphql`
       query ProductQuery {
        contentful: allContentfulProduct {
          products: edges {
            product: node {
              id
              name
              teaser {
                       teaser
                     }
            }
          }
       }}
       `}
    render={data => (

        data.contentful.products.map((product) => (
           <div className="col-md-4 inline">
             <h1>{product.product.name}</h1>
             {if (product.product.teaser !==null){
                <p>{product.product.teaser.teaser}</p>
             } 


             { console.log(product)}
           </div>

        )
     ))}
     />
)
```

When I remove the if block, the code runs fine, but with the if it wont compile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to compile, Unexpected token if in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42686424/failed-to-compile-unexpected-token-if-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `if` operator in-line inside of a curly brace expression like that. Try changing your syntax to:

```
{product.product.teaser !== null && (
    <p>{product.product.teaser.teaser}</p>
)}
```

More examples in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator